# Console.Log on contact form submit . Find out what email address it is sent to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am added an array of email address which the users selects in a drop down menu. That email is then sent the message that was just added . I am working on my localhost though and was wondering if there was a way in which i could find out specifically what email address was used in the POST event with console.log

Comment: you can see in the developer tools in network tab

Comment: You can always use fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler It basically monitors all in and out traffic and you can see what is being posted

Comment: @Canvas That looks amazing .. Thanks